# mysterious light

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I put in my scene a cube to block a light from outside and to fake a second floor above the stairs. However it did not blocked the light, the light from a hole in the ceiling was still polluting my scene. I put camera in the cube and find out that it looks like there is some light inside, even though there is none.

I trying to get rid of a light in my scene that is coming from nowhere. (The cube is light up inside even that it not supposed to be.)
[image]

I already switched every collection off (for that propose I put the cube in scene collection), made world shader black, even deleted the sun. No matter what material cube is made of there is still light inside. When I copy the cube to a different file it is acting like it supposed to (no mysterious light inside). The light doesn't depend on camera position. The cube is light-up from inside even when I close all it walls.

Render in Cycles.

I sharing a file with the cube and a camera to show the problem. I deleted everything else from the file.

[image]

Comment: That looks like Ambient Occlusion, more than lights. you could check that in World Properties > Ambient Occlusion

Comment: THX Emir. It helped. I thought that AO is only darkening the corners, so it was unexpected for me, would never find it out by myself.